# ERROR ITMS - 90167 No. app bundles found in the package on macOS Sierra

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode7.3

I am using **Xcode 7.3.1 on macOS Sierra** which I just updated **yesterday**.
Since I updated, I can't upload any more builds to Testflight; I always get this error message.

> ERROR ITMS - 90167 No. app bundles found in the package

I see from research that this problem only happens in the macOS Sierra beta, but I worry it's going to continue through the final release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a deep search and investigation, I finally decided that there is nothing wrong with our build. There was a problem when uploading our build with Apple iTunes Connect, which is that server denied uploading our build on **Xcode 7.3.1** on **macOS Sierra**. But, uploading with **Xcode 8** is working just fine. Just use the **Application Loader** from **Xcode 8** if you are not ready for Migration to Xcode 8, or if some of your project's third party libraries don't support **Swift 2.3**.

***So, how do I pass this?***

Simply, just install two version on Xcode: one to continue your development.And one for uploading the submit.

Here is how : https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/how_to_install_multiple_xcodes

Create an archive from your Xcode 7.3.1 and export an .ipa with with your production profile. Then upload that .ipa via the Xcode 8 Application Loader. This is inside the Xcode app bundle: Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app

You can also get to it inside of Xcode:

**Xcode menu > Open Developer Tools > Application Loader**

This is the only solution until Apple fixes it, believe me.